# Cloning a Mercurial repository over SSH

Tags: mercurial, ssh, webfaction

I'm having some difficulty cloning my mercurial repository over ssh.

Here's what I have tried:

```
hg clone ssh://username@username.webfactional.com/path/to/projectname projectname
```

It's giving me this error:

```
remote: bash: hg: command not found
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

hg is installed on the server, however.

I was trying to follow the instructions on [this website](http://echoreply.us/tuto/mercurial_site_management.html).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Sounds like `hg` is not on your path. The Mercurial FAQ mentions possible fixes for this issue: [FAQ/CommonProblems](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FAQ/CommonProblems).

Add the `remotecmd` value to your Mercurial configuration by opening `~/.hgrc` (or `Mercurial.ini` on Windows) on your client machine and adding the following:

```
[ui]
remotecmd = /path/to/hg
```

where `/path/to/hg` is the path to the `hg` command on the remote server.

If you're having problems with your Mercurial configuration, you can use the `hg showconfig --debug` command to obtain a full list of your Mercurial settings along with the path and line number of the configuration file that defines each configuration value.

Comment: I followed these directions and added remotecmd = ~/bin/hg to the hgrc file in my project and in my home folder, however it doesnt seem to find that. Adding --remotecmd to the command given in the question works, however. How can I get it so I don't have to type it in every time

Comment: Put it in your `.hgrc` configuration file in the `[ui]` section. See comment in answer.

Comment: You may have conflicts between your system-wide configuration, your user configuration and your project's configuration. Run `hg showconfig --debug` to see what your configuration is and where the values are derived from.

Comment: Have you tried setting `remotecmd` to the absolute path to `hg` on your remote machine?

Comment: Hmm. Do you set any default settings in the `[defaults]` section of any of your configuration files? It's possible that these might override/interfere with other configuration settings. Try removing any `[defaults]` that might relate to the `clone` command etc. and see if that makes any difference. However, it will most likely be easiest to change your bash profile on the remote system to ensure that `hg` is on the path.

Comment: I haven't touched the defaults. I tried to change the path in ~/.bash_profile from PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin to PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/home/jrs0390/bin and PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/home/jrs0390/bin/hg but neither of those worked

Comment: Try setting your path in `.bashrc`. Have you played with the `PermitUserEnvironment` setting in your `sshd_config` file? This article (http://serverfault.com/questions/130834/svnssh-getting-bash-to-load-my-path-over-ssh) discusses various settings and environment variables that might affect your `PATH`.

Comment: Glad we figured it out eventually!

Comment: remotecmd = /usr/local/bin/hg was the line I added to get my 'server' a Mac with mercurial to work with a pull request. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm doing the same as CenterOrbit (= HomeBrew's location for hg). Likely the problem with @Josh back in 2010 has been the use of ~. Should use absolute path - it's pointing at a remote machine anyway.

Comment: For one-off usage you can also give the remotecmd option on the command line instead of setting it permanently in .hgrc: `hg --config ui.remotecmd=/path/to/hg clone ...`

Answer (score 106):

You need a double // after hostname i.e.:

```
hg clone ssh://username@username.webfactional.com//path/to/projectname projectname
```

Comment: add [ui] remotecmd = /path/to/hg  as well use above string for connection

Comment: Why it works only with double `//` for me? Is this documented?

Comment: @gavenkoa: Because the first slash is not part of the path, but just the separator between host and path, so with one slash it's just a path relative to the user's home directory. The second slash makes it an absolute path.

Comment: hg clone ssh://host://path-to-repo/   ... if you have a configured hostname in ~.ssh/config

Answer (score 4):

Looks like mercurial isn't in your user's `PATH` on the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

On webfactional I had to add:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/<user>/bin
```

to .bashrc to get it to work.
(also followed the remotecmd advice above)

Comment: Adding `remotecmd` to a local `.hgrc` fixed the path issue. However, in my particular setup `remotecmd` introduced another error: `remote: conq: invalid command syntax`. Just adding the PATH value to `.bashrc` (on webfaction) was enough and really solved any issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

On the server, type: `nano ~/.bashrc` end edit the file by adding:

```
# User specific aliases and functions
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/packages/mercurial
```

Under the assumption that `~/packages` is the folder where mercurial was installed.
After editing, finish off with `source ~/.bashrc` and try again.

Pretty helpful to me was the following elaborate [guide to install mercurial on a Bluehost hosting server.](http://www.samanbarghi.com/2011/08/26/mercurial-on-bluehost/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sourcetree, TortoiseHg, Mercurial from the terminal, or any client you like to clone your Mercurial repository. These instructions show you how to clone your repository using Mercurial from the terminal.

1. From the repository, click + in the global sidebar and select Clone
   this repository under Get to work.
2. Copy the clone command (either the SSH format or the HTTPS).
   If you are using the SSH protocol, ensure your public key is in Bitbucket and loaded on the local system to which you are cloning.
3. From a terminal window, change to the local directory where you want to clone your repository.
4. Paste the command you copied from Bitbucket, for example:
   **CLONE OVER HTTPS**:
   `$ hg clone https://username@bitbucket.org/teamsinspace/hg-documentation-tests`
   **CLONE OVER SSH**:
   `$ hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/teamsinspace/hg-documentation-tests`
   If the clone was successful, a new sub-directory appears on your local drive.
   This directory has the same name as the Bitbucket repository that you cloned.
   The clone contains the files and metadata that Mercurial requires to maintain the changes you make to the source files.