# Push to remote Mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, ssh, push

I have a Mercurial repository on a remote [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). The VPS has SSH access enabled. What are my options for pushing code changes from my development machine to the remote VPS?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If your VPS has Mercurial installed, simply:

```
hg push ssh://username@host/path/relative/to/home
```

or add to the repo's hgrc

```
[paths]
default-push = ssh://username@host/path/relative/to/home
```

and just

```
hg push
```

Comment: FYI for anyone else that comes here, before attempting the above: When doing hg push, you need a double slash after hostname, for an absolute path. See [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431884/cloning-a-mercurial-repository-over-ssh#answer-8096666)

Comment: No, it's not needed, it just means something else. A double slash makes the path absolute on the host, a single slash is relative to home (as correctly mentioned in Lazy Badger's answer).

Comment: @RedGlyph, you are correct. I've updated my post to be slightly clearer about my meaning.

Comment: but what if i want to push to `/run/media/$DEVICE_LABEL`, not in home dir of user ?

Comment: @alexzander Then you would use the double slash after the hostname as mentioned by deadbeef404.