# Using Tortoisehg to push commits to mercurial on centos

Tags: mercurial, centos, tortoisehg

I'm trying to use a Centos VPS as a place to host my mercurial repositories, I'll init these repositories on the server and then clone them to my local computer using TortoiseHG.

I've setup a clean VPS with Centos 6 and taken the usual security steps such as root login disabled, changed ports, ssh key access only and a new user `user123`.

I connect to the server using pageant and ssh keys generated using puttygen.

I've setup a virtualhost that's only accessible to my local machines ips that's located at `/var/www/vhosts/hg/` all of my repositories are then accessible using `http://123.123.123.123/repositoryname/`

I've used `yum install mercurial` and can create repositories using `hg init`.

I can then succesfully clone my repositories to a local machine using the above url.

**The problem**

So far so good, however the issues arise when I try to push. At the moment I've not setup any sort of connection I'm just simply going on that I've been able to clone so I should be able to push (moronic).

However when I do try and push I get the following error from TortoiseHG:

```
abort: destination does not support push - command returned code 255
```

How do I go about adding support to be able to push to the above server configuration? Should I try and get it to use pageant or do I need additional server software so support pushing?

I'm not really sure of what the next step is and Googling hasn't yielded any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all of my repositories are then accessible using `http://123.123.123.123/repositoryname/`

Bad configuration... and probably totally wrong idea of using http, when you have ssh

- Which http-frontend do you use?
- Did you integrate (any) frontend with Mercurial?
- Have you [push enabled](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Allowing_push)?

In case of `ssh://`-served repositories your [task may be a lot simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623607/push-to-remote-mercurial-repository)

Comment: The SSH method works perfectly, can remove all of http stuff now, thanks!