# Mercurial: remote: abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!

Tags: mercurial, ssh

all,

I have searched for this problem for long time and tried different methods.

I want to maintain my code on the server through only SSH. But when I run this:

```
sudo hg clone -v ssh://carl@hostname//home/carl/Java/Projects/peta/
```

Mercurial keeps telling me `remote: abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!`. Some articles said that the path should be correct and there should be a `.hg` directory there. But I have checked it for several times and I am sure there is a `.hg` folder at the right place.

I also tried

```
hg --config ui.remotecmd=/usr/bin/hg clone ssh://carl@hostname//home/carl/Java/Projects/peta/
```

But it failed as well. What other problem it could be? Thanks.

---

#### Solved

I finally fix the problem. Previously, I create a repository on my local machine, and scp all files (including `.hg`) on to the server. I try to remove `.hg` directory first, and create a repo on the server through ssh (`hg init`). Then `hg clone` works!

Comment: Is there a mercurial repository (not only a .hg folder) at /home/carl/Java/Projects/peta/? Can you run `hg log` from there?

Comment: If you have an hg server on windows and running a cygwin ssh server, then try `ssh://myuser@machinex.com/D:/repos` rather than `ssh://myuser@machinex.com//cygdrive/d/repos`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Extraction from `hg help urls`

> Some notes about using SSH with Mercurial:
>
> - SSH requires an accessible shell account on the destination machine and
>       a copy of hg in the remote path or specified with as remotecmd.
> - path is relative to the remote user's home directory by default. Use an
>       extra slash at the start of a path to specify an absolute path:
>
>   ssh://example.com//tmp/repository

this means, at least, that **you can't use the same URI** and change only one/two slash it it: at least one path will be non-existent.

Consequence of the quote and error message: you **must** to debug (with any ssh-tool) and find correct path to needed directory. you can:

- use scp (f.e) and copy known file from known location
- SSH into remote host in interactive session and verify path (both?) by hand, i.e: ssh ..., cd ..., pwd, verify output of pwd
- ... any other debugger

When you'll get good path after login, you have to check next point of failure - .hg dir permissions

After verification of these checkpoints you'll get clone and some bonus in the form of understanding "What happened before"

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this really helps but, according to the [FAQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-CommonProblems.I_get_an_error_while_cloning_a_remote_repository_via_ssh):

```
hg clone ssh://USER@REMOTE/path/to/repo
```

They are using only one `/` after the `USER@HOST`. Maybe you can try that way.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried it already, not working. I am wondering whether I should do some configuration on the server?

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431884/cloning-a-mercurial-repository-over-ssh

Comment: I tried it as well, César. It is not working... That is why I am so crazy about this....

Comment: I really hope you can do it! A workaround: you can always push the repository from your remote host (ssh host) to, say, Bitbucket (https://bitbucket.org/). And then clone that repository via http from your local machine :) I do that all the time. Cheers

Comment: I finally fix the problem. Previously, I create a repository on my local machine, and scp all files (including .hg) on to the server. I try to remove .hg directory first, and create a repo through ssh (hg init). Then it works!

Answer (score 0):

César Bustíos's answer is almost correct, but that tries to clone from remote to local. To opposite way, we have to add the local path. In the case it is the current directory, it will be a dot.

```
hg clone . ssh://USER@REMOTE/path/to/repo
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Running on Debian, to solve my problem, I have added the following line to my `/var/lib/mercurial-server/.mercurial-server` configuration file after the `[paths]`

```
[paths]
/ = ~/repos
...
```

And don't forget to issue this command afterwards: `sudo -u hg /usr/share/mercurial-server/refresh-auth`