# .hg not found when performing [hg out]

Tags: mercurial

I create a local repo with

```
local-host $ hg init ~/test/
```

and then in the remote host i do a clone

```
remote-host $ hg clone ssh://user@local-host/test
```

without any issues.

When im trying to check if there are outgoing changes in the remote repo im getting this error

```
remote-host $ cd test
remote-host $ hg --verbose out
comparing with ssh://user@local-host/test
running ssh user@local-host 'hg -R test serve --stdio'
searching for changes
no changes found
remote: abort: no repository found in '/home/user' (.hg not found)!
remote: abort: no repository found in '/home/user' (.hg not found)!
```

If i commit any change in the remote/local repository and push it im getting the error but the change gets pushed.

Both hosts have the same mercurial version.

Any ideas ?

Comment: is the repository located in `~/test` on the remote machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493733/mercurial-remote-abort-there-is-no-mercurial-repository-here-hg-not-found

Answer (score 0):

You need to let it know **which** repository - easiest is:

```
remote-host $ cd ~/test/ 
remote-host $ hg --verbose out
```

Comment: I am trying to do "hg --verbose out" in the mercurial repo (i updated the example code with a "cd test" to make it clear).

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al` in your repository?

Comment: `total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4096 Jun 30 12:45 .
drwxrwxr-x 26 user user 4096 Jun 30 12:45 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4096 Jun 30 12:45 .hg` (how do i do multiline in the replys ? :p)